# Importing shapefile into GRASS, and multiple new rows appear in attribute table

Tags: qgis, shapefile, grass-gis, attribute-table, import

I am importing a GADM Global Administrative Areas shapefile into GRASS (using QGIS 2.8.2 interface).

When I do this, multiple additional rows are created in the attribute table.

It goes from this:

[image: Original Attribute Table]

To this:

[image: Attribute Table After Import]

This makes it difficult to work with. I am using v.in.ogr with and without the "-c" flag, but this doesn't make a difference.

Is there anything I can do to keep the attribute table in the original form?

There is a [discussion](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2010-August/057441.html) on importing GADM into GRASS stating that importing causes it to crash, but it doesn't help here. Further I am importing a very small subset of GADM (~20 polygons, some with edges touching). There is [documentation](https://github.com/AmericanRedCross/simplegadm) on simplifying GADM, but this is beyond my capabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the "key" parameter of [v.in.ogr](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.in.ogr.html) and define it in a way that the ID column is used.

In your case try "ID_0" as name of column used for categories (i.e. "key=ID_0"). If not given, categories are generated as unique values and stored in 'cat' column - this is what happened in your case so far.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! This works perfectly. I had to install GRASS 7.0.1, as the "key" parameter doesn't seem to be available on the version of GRASS which is currently available through QGIS (v.6).

Comment: Good - and you may enjoy all the http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Grass7/NewFeatures